# How to construct a proper action of a group of finite virtual cohomological dimension?

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-actions

Let $\Gamma$ be the semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4$,
where the action of $\mathbb{Z}/4$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ is defined by $\bar{k} \cdot x = (-1)^k x$. Clearly $\Gamma$ has virtual cohomological dimension (*vcd*) one.

Is it possible to construct a one-dimensional contractible CW complex $X$
such that $\Gamma$ acts cellularly on $X$ and the cells have only finite
stabilizers?

$\mathbb{Z}$ acts freely on $\mathbb{R}$ by right-shift. I tried without
success to adjust this action to obtain an action of $\Gamma$. So any help
is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean ${\mathbb Z}/2$ instead of ${\mathbb Z}/4$?

Comment: Can't you let it act on the real line with $\mathbb Z$ acting by integral translations and the generator of ${\mathbb Z}/4$ acting by multiplication by $(-1)$?

Comment: A virtually cyclic group always has proper action on the real line.

Comment: More generally a finitely generated group has a cocompact proper action on a tree iff it has a finite index free subgroup.

Comment: @Corbennick: Indeed, this works by defining $(x,\bar{k})\cdot r = x + (1)^kr$ where $x \in \mathbb{Z}, \bar{k} \in \mathbb{Z}/4, r \in \mathbb{R}$. I had tried  $(x,\bar{k})\cdot r = (1)^k(x+r)$ which didn't work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, the point is that the group surjects $D_\infty$ with finite ($\mathbb{Z}/2$) kernel. I'm tempted to vote to close (as this was barely reserch level), but perhaps @Corbennick could at least post their comment as a answer?

Comment: In the formular above, of course, I mean (-1) in place of (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let it act on the real line with ℤ acting by integral translations and the generator of ℤ/4 acting by multiplication by (−1).